# Can we Enable notifications preferences on CloudSQL by terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCgGl.png)

i can see there is only option to enable from google cloud console.
is it possible to set the notifications by terraform modules for cloud sql in GCP?

if possible could you please share me the module i will add into my scripts..

tried some testing by adding alerting module into the sql but it's not working.

Comment: AFAIK and considering how it's done on the UI, I would say "no"

Comment: From the screenshot, this seems to be a setting in the user's preferences. I doubt that there is a Terraform module, as well. Also: You'd need to have the user in your Terraform state, otherwise you wouldn't be able to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `google_monitoring_notification_channel` @ https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_notification_channel

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "default" {
  display_name = "Test Slack Channel"
  type         = "slack"
  labels = {
    "channel_name" = "#foobar"
  }
  sensitive_labels {
    auth_token = "one"
  }
}
```

I have not tested this myself, so please comment if this works for you(if not I will delete this).

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/user-preferences/communication?cloudshell=false


This is the link which i wanted to enable the notifications for cloudsql, cloud memory store....etc

The above module will create a notification channel like email, sms, slack.. i'm using this module for uptime checks, gke pods, sql cpu usage..

I think this module doesn't support for product notifications in GCP.